# How to change overlays checkbox feature in layerlist to radio button

Tags: openlayers-2

How to change the default check box button of Overlays in Layerlist to radio buttons. My client doesn't want his users to see more than one layer on the map.

Is there any way that we can prevent the possibility to check multiple layers in overlay layers in the LayerList?

Comment: Please help me for this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112792/how-to-change-overlays-as-radio-button-and-accordian-list-in-layer-switcher-cont?sem=2

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding this option to your layers?

```
displayInLayerSwitcher: false
```

Here is my second answer. I have not tested it but I believe it will work.

In \Control\LayerSwitcher.js change the line, line 331 in what I am looking at, from:

```
    inputElem.type = (baseLayer) ? "radio" : "checkbox";
```

to:

```
    inputElem.type = (baseLayer) ? "checkbox" : "radio";
```

to see the change you will need to load the uncompressed OL code.

Comment: Hi Ralph no i didnot add this feature to my code. I will try now.

Comment: Hi I have added this feature to my overlay layers but i do not see any change, can you post any sample working code. Here is my code that i use to add layers to my map object.              var wms_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('layer','url:8080/geoserver/wms/land_upplift',{layers: 'layer', transparent: "true", format: "image/png"},{opacity: "0.6"});

Comment: Hi Ralph {displayInLayerSwitcher: false} this feature completely remove the layer in the layerlist. I do not want to remove the layer in the layerlist insted i want to change the checkbox feature  to radio button.

Comment: I see. I did not totally understand what you were trying to accomplish. I do not use the built in layer list. Can you post a picture of what you have and where you are trying to go?

Comment: Hi Ralph, here is the webpage of my application(http://geoserver.natgeo.su.se/karteek/test.html). In the layerlist control, by default openlayers assign radio button for baselayers and checkbox for overlays. I want to change this default function of checkbox of overlays to radio button.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to your problem can be to make add all layers as Base layer. Just add property

```
isBaseLayer: true
```

to your layer.